# How do I get HTML rendered as markdown via GitHub Pages?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, r-markdown, github-flavored-markdown, kramdown

I have a rather nasty, huge HTML document that I converted to markdown.

When I do the usual layout and view the .md file in GitHub via preview tab, it looks fine. However, when I serve it and view it on my actual site, it renders all the HTML tags.

I have tried using different markdown interpreters like redcarpet versus kramdown, to no avail.

How do I get a good markdown rendering of HTML similar to the GitHub behavior?

[Link to repo](https://github.com/remerjohnson/remerjohnson.github.io/blob/master/test.md)  (notice the clean GitHub Flaovred markdown)

Comment: Far better with a link to you repository.

Comment: Thanks. Edited now with a link to the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a markdown but a html document.

Rename it to `test.html`

Remove `html` and `body` tags

give it a :

```
---
layout: page
title: Test
permalink: /test2/
---
```

I've made a pull request that works to you repo.

Note: before pasting word html to the web you can clean it.